# javascript: onClick="" vs. jQuery.Click()

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I have many pages with onClick-Events(every page got other elements with it's own onClick-Event). All pages get included to one main-Page (`index.php`)

Thus, I can't put all of the jQuery onClick-Events in the head of the page (because the `<head>` is just in `index.php`, not in the included pages)

Is it now better to either make a `<script>...</script>` in every page I include? Because this wouldn't be in the `<head>`.

Or should I use the `HTML`-attribute `onClick=""` ?

Comment: Scripts don't normally go in the head, they go just before </body>. If you can't add a script element to each page in one go, you need to rethink your code architecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it now better to either make a ... in every page I
>   include? Because this wouldn't be in the .

`<script>` tags don't need to be in the head, actually, the best place (performance-wise) is right before the closing `</body>`. And yes, you also want to use external JS files as much as possible.

> Or should I use the HTML-attribute onClick="" ?
>   [...]
>   I can't put all of the jQuery onClick-Events in the head of the page
>   (because the  is just in index.php, not in the included pages)

In general, you almost always want to avoid adding lots of events, instead, you want to take advantage of event bubbling using `jQuery.on`.

An example usage might be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.myselector', function(e) {
        alert('Parameter: ' + $(this).attr('data-param'));
    });
});
```

You HTML would look something like:

```
<a href="#" class="myselector" data-param="Hello!">This is a button</a>
```

This will bind only *one* event, on the body. When you click on anything inside the body, the event will bubble up to the body, and get executed if you clicked inside this selector.
If there's no `.myselector` on the page, it'll do nothing, so that would be okay.

Comment: That's a good idea.

But I need different parameters for a function that I call with the `onClick`-Event. For Example, button 1 sends parameter 'XY' to the function when it gets clicked and button 2 sends parameter 'AB' to the function. Is to possible to achieve this?

Comment: @Akeno The general pattern for that is using `data-` attributes on your buttons. I've updated my answer to include an example.

Comment: thanks for that example. That sounds promising. One last question about it. Is it possible to have more than one `data-param` in one element? For example, if I need more parameters for a function?

Comment: Yes, you can have as many as you want, but, obviously, you can't name them the same (ie. you can't have two `data-param` attributes). You probably want to give them meaningful names (such as `data-location`, or `data-action`, etc.), you can choose any name you want. You could also use a single `data-` attribute, and split the value by comma.

Answer (score 2):

Really, all JavaScript should be placed in external files. This is for performance and maintainability.

Performance because external scripts can be cached by the browser, decreasing loading times.

Maintainability because you don't end up having to trawl through massive HMTL documents to get to a bit of JavaScript.

JavaScript within HMTL can also mess with the parser, which you need to be aware of.

If it's not possible to include all your scripts in external files you should really re-think your website's architecture, as this is how it should be.

Comment: thanks.

I don't know how I could alter my architecture. It's just, that I load the content via Ajax.

I Have index.php and when you click on button1, $.ajax() calls page1.php which displays content of page1.php. Same with button2 and so on. I can't imagine another way to to this. Even with 'normal' pages without anything to include I would need different javascript per page I think

Comment: You can still include them all in the main JavaScript file, you'd just need to bind the `.Click()` events for a particular page only when it's loaded in (after the AJAX call completes).

Answer (score 0):

Read about `Unobstrusive Javascript`:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: Yes, but I work with Ajax and I don't know any other way to work with Ajax. Because I want to avoid reloading the page for some trivial things. Many pages try to, I think. Do they all use some other tricks?